# Compressing Numbers: Reading Error

Tags: c, numbers, compression

I am using this function for compression of Numbers:

```
unsigned char *MyCompress(unsigned int num, unsigned char *buffer){
    int     i = 0;
    unsigned int r = num;
    unsigned char temp;
    unsigned char s[5];

    printf("received %d to compress\n", num);

    if(!r){
       *buffer++ = 0;
       return buffer;
    }

    while (r){
         s[i] = r & 127;
         r >>= 7;
         printf("s[%d]=%d; r=%d\n", i, s[i], r);
         i++;
    }
    while (--i >= 0){
         temp = (unsigned char)(s[i] | (i ? 128 : 0));
         printf("temp=%d\n", temp);
         *buffer++=temp;
    }
  return buffer;
}
```

//Now sending to Print this number

```
 unsigned char *abc, *abc2;
 abc=(unsigned char *)malloc(10);
 abc2=abc;
 len=384;
 abc = MyCompress(len, abc);
 fwrite(abc2, 1, (abc-abc2), fp);
```

//Output

```
 s[0]=0; r=3;
 s[1]=3; r=0

 temp=131
 temp=0
```

Now Getting Error While Reading:

```
 unsigned int MyDeCompress(FILE *fp){
    unsigned int c;
    unsigned int num = 0;

    do{
       c = (unsigned) fgetc(fp);
       printf(Read="%d\n", c);
       if (c <= 0) {
          printf("c is < 0 in uncompress1()\n");
          exit(0);
       }
       num <<= 7;
       num |= c & 127;

       printf("uncompress: c = %d num = %d\n", c, num);

       if (!num)
          break;
    }while (c & 128);
    printf("Returning %d\n", num);
    return num;
 }
```

//Output

```
  Read=131
  uncompress: c = 3 num = 3
  Returning 3
```

Why it is Returning 3. How can I get again 384. 
But other numbers are reading correctly.

## update

I want the logic solution of the problem. Not about Memory Leaks or How to Read File or How to Write File. Kindly provide solution to the problem what can be done.

Comment: Wow, hang on a second. `abc = malloc(...)` and then `abc = MyCompress(...)`??? You're surely going to get memory leaks for that. Something in your program design is fundamentally wrong to begin with!

Comment: Well, they're just a (very bad) symptom of your problem. Your design is flawed. And that **is** a problem. In function `MyCompress`, use an index to `buffer`, increment that index when needed and return it when done. Keep `abc` as is. Do **not** change it. In fact, it is not even clear why you're dynamically allocating it to begin with, as its size is constant (10 entries). You might as well use an array. In any case, use an index to this buffer (or statically allocate array as I have suggested) **inside and outside** of function `MyCompress`.

Comment: Oh, well, I see you've just updated your code in the question (using `abc2 = abc`). Was that in your code before, or have you just added it now? If you've just added it now (including the `fwrite` with `abc2`), then it pretty much proves that you had a problem in the exact place I pointed out on the first comment, doesn't it? I said you had a memory leak which indicated a flaw in your design (changing the value of `abc`) and that statement looks pretty accurate now that you've fixed that in the code.

Comment: @barakmanos There are lot of other things going on which would make question more complex. I want to know the solution of the problem as memory leaks are not problem. If the solution is correct to cover memory leaks we can change the code n number of times. But if the solution is not correction then what fun of taking care of memory leaks

Comment: Let me summarize and emphasize those first two comments of mine up there one more time: **The memory leaks are just a very bad symptom of your problem. Updating the value of `abc` and then using this pointer in order to write into the file is at least one problem that you have. Aside of those memory leaks, it probably yields something else (other than what you expect) in the file.** Now, you seem to have fixed that since I posted those two comments, right? This means that it was indeed more than "just a minor" memory leak problem, right?

Comment: The fact that you continue to insist that what I've pointed out has nothing to do with your problem (yet you've fixed it immediately afterwards), kind of making me reluctant to give any more advices...

Comment: By induction, next time I point out a problem, you will fix it in your question and say that it is not the main problem. When I point out the last problem, you will probably delete the question altogether...

Comment: BTW, you've got a bunch of other problems in function `MyDeCompress` with variable `c` being `unsigned`. First of all, what's the point of checking `c <= 0`? You might as well check `c == 0`, because it can never be less than 0. Perhaps that is indeed your problem, since you are not terminating the loop when `c == EOF`. In addition, what on earth does `printf(Read="%d\n", c)` mean???

Comment: "Seems that you don't have knowledge of Bit Manipulation"???? And then you're asking me to provide an earlier solution??? Hmmmm... strange logic...

Answer (score 0):

You did not actually run the code you posted in the question.  Posting code is a good thing, but only if it is the actual code that you ran and are having a problem with, and if you cut and paste it verbatim, directly into the question.

Once I put the `Read=` inside the quotes where it belongs, your code does not do what you claim it does.  It returns 131 out when you put 131 in.  You do not have a problem.  Well, at least not with 131.

There are problems with your code, other than strings that have strayed outside of their quotes.

This:

```
    if (c <= 0) {
        printf("c is <= 0 in uncompress1()\n");
        exit(0);
    }
```

shouldn't be there at all.  As was already pointed out, the `<` in the `<=` is pointless since `c` is unsigned, but more importantly, zero is a perfectly valid value to have in your coded data, e.g. whenever the low seven bits of the number are all zeros.  The number 128 codes to 129 0.

For the zero case, you should remove the `if(!r){` section and simply make the loop `do while` instead of `while`.

When you're reading from a file, you need to look for end of file and deal with it.