# Why My DeCompression is showing an Error?

Tags: c, compression

The Code is also provided here and runing perfectly and showing errors - http://ideone.com/gWEoIV

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned char *MyCompress(unsigned int num, unsigned char *buffer);
unsigned int MyDeCompress(unsigned char **buffer);

int main(void) {
    unsigned char *abc, *abc2;
    unsigned len;
    abc=(unsigned char *)malloc(12);
    abc2=abc;
    len=25960;
    abc = MyCompress(len, abc);
    len=385;
    abc = MyCompress(len, abc);
    len=900;
    abc = MyCompress(len, abc);
    len=20560;
    abc = MyCompress(len, abc);
    len=384;
    abc = MyCompress(len, abc);
    abc=abc2;

    len = MyDeCompress(&abc);
    len = MyDeCompress(&abc);
    len = MyDeCompress(&abc);
    len = MyDeCompress(&abc);
    len = MyDeCompress(&abc);


    return 0;
}

unsigned int MyDeCompress(unsigned char **buffer){
    unsigned int c;
    unsigned int num = 0;
    unsigned char *p = *buffer;

    printf("\n\nDeCompression\n===============\n");

    do{
        c = ((unsigned char) *p++);
        printf("Read=%d\n", c);
        if (c <= 0) {
            printf("Error: c is < 0 in uncompress1()\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        num <<= 7;
        num |= c & 127;

        printf("uncompress: c = %d num = %d\n", c, num);

        if (!num)
            break;
    }while (c & 128);

    *buffer = p;

    printf("Returning %d\n", num);

    return num;
}


unsigned char *MyCompress(unsigned int num, unsigned char *buffer){
    int i = 0;
    unsigned int r = num;
    unsigned char temp;
    unsigned char s[5];

    printf("Compression\n===============\n");

    printf("received %d to compress\n", num);

    if(!r){
        *buffer++ = 0;
        return buffer;
    }

    while (r){
        s[i] = r & 127;
        r >>= 7;
        printf("s[%d]=%d; r=%d\n", i, s[i], r);
        i++;
    }

    while (--i >= 0){
        temp = (unsigned char)(s[i] | (i ? 128 : 0));
        printf("temp=%d\n", temp);
        *buffer++=temp;
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

//Output:

```
Compression
===============
received 25960 to compress
s[0]=104; r=202
s[1]=74; r=1
s[2]=1; r=0
temp=129
temp=202
temp=104
Compression
===============
received 385 to compress
s[0]=1; r=3
s[1]=3; r=0
temp=131
temp=1
Compression
===============
received 900 to compress
s[0]=4; r=7
s[1]=7; r=0
temp=135
temp=4
Compression
===============
received 20560 to compress
s[0]=80; r=160
s[1]=32; r=1
s[2]=1; r=0
temp=129
temp=160
temp=80
Compression
===============
received 384 to compress
s[0]=0; r=3
s[1]=3; r=0
temp=131
temp=0


DeCompression
===============
Read=129
uncompress: c = 129 num = 1
Read=202
uncompress: c = 202 num = 202
Read=104
uncompress: c = 104 num = 25960
Returning 25960


DeCompression
===============
Read=131
uncompress: c = 131 num = 3
Read=1
uncompress: c = 1 num = 385
Returning 385


DeCompression
===============
Read=135
uncompress: c = 135 num = 7
Read=4
uncompress: c = 4 num = 900
Returning 900


DeCompression
===============
Read=129
uncompress: c = 129 num = 1
Read=160
uncompress: c = 160 num = 160
Read=80
uncompress: c = 80 num = 20560
Returning 20560


DeCompression
===============
Read=131
uncompress: c = 131 num = 3
Read=0
Error: c is < 0 in uncompress1()
```

Why I am getting Error: when DeCompress 384 number?

Comment: Does it fit? What is the value of `abc-abc2` after the last compress?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compressing Numbers: Reading Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368124/compressing-numbers-reading-error)

Answer (score 0):

You already asked this question, and I already answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26372625/1180620).  Zero is an expected byte in your coding scheme, and must not be rejected.  Simply delete the `if (c <= 0)` section.

Comment: if I don't know about 0 then how would i know about end of file or line terinator is reached.

Comment: If end-of-file doesn't work for you, because you have other data after the stream of numbers and the number of numbers is variable, then you can use a disallowed sequence as a terminator.  The byte 128 is a disallowed start for your encoding, so that can terminate the list of numbers.

Comment: You are absolutely right but if you see the compressing is according to 7 bits and in 7 bits not possible to write 128 thus I have write 0 for that and it acts as terminator or Error symbol

Comment: That's the point.  128 cannot come out of your encoding of an integer.  So write the byte 128, separately from your encoding routine, to terminate the list of integers.  In your decoding routine, detect an initial 128 and return an indication that the end of the stream was reached.

Comment: I have gone through your advice that 128 means the ending of string where ever 0 comes it would be changed with 128. But then another problem arises with number 983055 compression shows 188 128 15 which is returning 7680 and last byte is not added in it.

Comment: I have pasted the code at http://ideone.com/gWEoIV if you correct it would be gr8.

Comment: 128 is forbidden as the _first_ byte of an encoded integer.  So when you go to decode your next integer and the first byte is a 128, then it's not an encoded integer and instead signals the end of your stream.

Comment: I already told you what to do to fix your code in two answers here on stackexchange.  That is already more than you should expect, since this is not a site to dump your code in and expect other people to fix it.

Comment: First, delete the `if (c <= 0) {` section.  Second, delete the `if(!r){` section and replace the `while (r){}` with `do {} while (r);`.  You can detect the end-of-stream signal (128) by checking for `c == 128` on the exit of the `do` loop in `MyDeCompress()`.  This is enabled by your `if (!num) break;`, which I would remove and replace with a change to the `do` condition, changing `}while (c & 128);` to `}while ((c & 128) && num);`.  You need to provide a length with your `buffer` parameters and check it to make sure that you don't run past the buffer when reading or writing.